# How to add a dropdown menu to the Navigation Bar Title in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I want to make something similar to the dropdown menu in these screenshots. How would I go about doing that?

[image]

When you tap the title, the arrow points up and a menu drops down. The App Is College Menus.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are lots of cocoacontrols to perform this function in your app:

[DropDown Menu Controls For iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=down%20menu)

But I think [lmdropdownview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lmdropdownview) is the most accurate.

My mistake, [btnavigationdropdownmenu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/btnavigationdropdownmenu) ITS the most accurate for what you are asking (according to your screens).

Implementation (Swift)[See the readme for more speceific instructions, and customization]:

```
let items = ["Most Popular", "Latest", "Trending", "Nearest", "Top Picks"]

let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(frame:  CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 44), title: items.first!, items: items, containerView: self.view)

self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView

menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {(indexPath: Int) -> () in
            println("Did select item at index: \(indexPath)")
            self.selectedCellLabel.text = items[indexPath]
}
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Thanks for 'rsc' for the info, theres an [objective-c version](https://github.com/PerfectFreeze/PFNavigationDropdownMenu) of this cocoacontrol:

```
    #import "PFNavigationDropdownMenu.h"


-(void)viewDidLoad{
    PFNavigationDropdownMenu *menuView = [[PFNavigationDropdownMenu alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)title:items.firstObjects items:items containerView:self.view];

    menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = ^(NSUInteger indexPath){
            NSLog(@"Did select item at index: %ld", indexPath);
            self.selectedCellLabel.text = items[indexPath];
        };

        self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView;

    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/PerfectFreeze/PFNavigationDropdownMenu - Objective-C variant of BTNavigationDropdownMenu

Answer (score 6):

Possible workaround if you prefer doing it manually:

Create two `UIButton` (up/down), assign the first one to `navigationItem.titleView`, add action for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` on this action check if states changing to expanding or collapsing and dependent on that add/remove `UITableView` with empty dataSource on top of your `UIViewController` `view`, set proper frame. Then update datasource and either reload with row animation `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` or `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` dependent on if it's expanding or collapsing. Replace button with second one.