# Add Uitableview dynamically while user search on Uisearchbar on navigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

Please find attachment and check "reference.png"[image] screen for more detail.
I need same implementation on iOS. I add uisearchbar on navigation bar. now when user search UItableview should popup dynamically based on user Input.

I make dynamic uitableview and add this like this way.

```
self.table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[self.tabBar addSubview:self.table];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.table];
self.table.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

But it's not look proper. i also attach screenshot for this too.

[image]

Comment: Used this Answer . I thik this one is help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617810/how-to-add-a-dropdown-menu-to-the-navigation-bar-title-in-ios

Comment: It will be better if you add a tableview from storyboard and then hide and unhide it, then you can design it more nicely.